# Problem installing baselines !!! OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor

Tags: python, pytest

I have Python 3.7, was following instructions in https://github.com/openai/baselines, I got to the step "Testing the installation", which says to do the following:

```
pip install pytest
pytest
```

Here, I ran into a problem:

```
Exception ignored in: <function SubprocVecEnv.__del__ at 0x1c348c2b90>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/daveloui/GitHub/RND/random-network-distillation/baselines/baselines/common/vec_env/subproc_vec_env.py", line 121, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "/Users/daveloui/GitHub/RND/random-network-distillation/baselines/baselines/common/vec_env/vec_env.py", line 98, in close
    self.close_extras()
  File "/Users/daveloui/GitHub/RND/random-network-distillation/baselines/baselines/common/vec_env/subproc_vec_env.py", line 104, in close_extras
    remote.send(('close', None))
  File "/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_114/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 206, in send
    self._send_bytes(_ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))
  File "/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_114/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 404, in _send_bytes
    self._send(header + buf)
  File "/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_114/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 368, in _send
    n = write(self._handle, buf)
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

There is more to this error, but it was too long to post it all.

Answer (score 0):

Solution found when the following missing dependencies were installed:

```sh
pip install filelock
brew install libav-tools
pip install gym[atari]
pip install pandas
pip install matplotlib
```